# Java Casting a Generic Class with a specific type without warnings

Tags: java, android, generics, casting

I have a class ListFragment

```
 public class ListFragment<T> extends DialogFragment {
```

when i try to cast an object to a specific type of `ListFragment` in this case a `String`

```
ListFragment<String> lfst = (ListFragment<String>)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("somePicker");
```

It gives me a warning **Type safety: Unchecked cast from Fragment to ListFragment**

To remove the warning I have to add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`

The reason I need `ListFragment<String>` as I will be calling a method that depends on the use of `String`.

So is there a way to achieve this without using a suppress warning. Note this code is being written for use on Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, no.  The `findFragmentByTag` method doesn't know that it will be returning a `ListFragment` and the superclass, `Fragment`, has no type parameters itself.

The best that you can do is suppress the warning as you have done.

Comment: Thanks I am new to Java, so when I saw the warning I thought there must be a better way of approaching this than what I was doing.

Answer (score -1):

It is just a warning. run it, test it and if all goes well. leave it. you can supress every single warning in your application. Good luck

Comment: True, although I do admire the question's quest for zero warnings.

Comment: Not sure why i got a minus for this.

End of the day, if your unit tests passes and functional and user testing passes then why be concerned about the warnings?